# Updating a data.frame column with eval function

Tags: r, dataframe, eval

I have a data.frame df with 2 columns in R and I need to update one of the columns by using a `eval` function (or by any other way) based on the values in the other column. `Col1` is a character column and I need to evaluate the expression and update the result in `Col2`.
So, for the first row it would be -0.49, for the last one: -0.26.
I tried this approach but it updates all the values with the result from last row's evaluation:

```
df["Col2"] <- eval(parse(text=df$Col1))


Col1                     Col2
------------------------------
20.31 - 20.80            0
51.81 - 52.22            0
44.07 - 44.88            0
42.94 - 43.47            0
18.93 - 19.15            0
27.42 - 27.68            0
```

I got this unexpected result:

```
Col1                     Col2
------------------------------
20.31 - 20.80            -0.26
51.81 - 52.22            -0.26
44.07 - 44.88            -0.26
42.94 - 43.47            -0.26
18.93 - 19.15            -0.26
27.42 - 27.68            -0.26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that if you pass `eval` a vector of expressions, it only returns the last result. I'm not sure why that is the desired behavior, but that is how it is documented on the `?eval` help page:

> (The function returns) The result of evaluating the object: for an expression vector this is the result of evaluating the last element.

So you can get around this with a friendly `sapply` statement.

```
sapply(df$Col1, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
```

And that should give you the vector of results you were expecting.

Comment: Of course I would strongly consider other alternatives that don't use the `eval` function, especially on non-trusted data, as it could be potentially dangerous. I don't know what values are allowed in that column, but if it's always number-minus-number, it might be better to `strsplit` on the minus, parse the numbers with `as.numeric` and do the subtraction yourself.