# Why eval parse cannot be used to evaluate string as formula

Tags: r, parsing, dataframe, eval

R Why eval parse cannot be used to evaluate string as formula

In this question I would like to know if it is possible in R to evaluate a string as a formula.
 The formula should be composed of more than two pre existing columns in a data.frame, 
 which permits the formula to be evaluated with varying argument values across the rows of the data.frame.

I have the following example:

```
# 1) Loading data
data(mtcars)

# 2) Creates a string formula using two arguments ( ideal to use three or more arguments )
mtcars$formulafx <- sprintf( 'mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == %s & mtcars[,10] == %i , 1] )' , mtcars$cyl , mtcars$gear )

 # 3) Incorrect result and really slow when used with only one argument formula
mtcars$resultsfx <- eval( parse( text = mtcars$formulafx ) )
```

I have been searching the internet for similar questions.
 I have found the following to be related:
 [Updating a data.frame column with eval function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508270/updating-a-data-frame-column-with-eval-function)

I have tested the same using `as.formula` function but no result either.

I would like to be sure that:

- This approach is simply not possible in R.
- There is other solution in R.

==============================

EDIT:

I thank Sathish's solution. It works, but I have tested this solution in a data.frame consisting of 101.815 rows and the result is the following:

```
user  system elapsed 
165.46   11.45  177.11
```

Almost 3 minutes. In practice this is not really good. I will thank suggestions.

Comment: Whatever you are actually trying to do with `eval(parse...` in your real problem, I would encourage you to think of an alternative. There's almost no need to ever use such a method of programming in R.

Comment: [R fortunes 106 and 181](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf) rear their ugly heads!

Comment: It seems to me that you just need `ave(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$cyl,mtcars$gear,FUN=mean)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using  `lapply`

```
unlist( lapply( mtcars$formulafx, function( x ) eval( parse( text = x ) ) ) )
# [1] 19.750 19.750 26.925 19.750 15.050 19.750 15.050 26.925 26.925 19.750 19.750 15.050 15.050
# [14] 15.050 15.050 15.050 15.050 26.925 26.925 26.925 21.500 15.050 15.050 15.050 15.050 26.925
# [27] 28.200 28.200 15.400 19.700 15.400 26.925
```

using `sapply`

```
sapply( mtcars$formulafx, function( x ) eval( parse( text = x ) ) )
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 6 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 19.750 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 6 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 19.750 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 6 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 19.750 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 6 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 19.750 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 6 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 19.750 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 6 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 19.750 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 21.500 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 3 , 1] ) 
# 15.050 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 5 , 1] ) 
# 28.200 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 5 , 1] ) 
# 28.200 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 5 , 1] ) 
# 15.400 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 6 & mtcars[,10] == 5 , 1] ) 
# 19.700 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 8 & mtcars[,10] == 5 , 1] ) 
# 15.400 
# mean( mtcars[mtcars[,2] == 4 & mtcars[,10] == 4 , 1] ) 
# 26.925
```